# Search word in all Telegram groups with telethon

Tags: telegram, telethon

Is it possible to search for one or multiple words in messages on ALL telegram groups using Telethon?

For example i'm member in only one telegram group "One".
I want to search in ALL groups for "promotion" and "bonus" in their group messages.
I didn't know the name of the group and I'm not a member - just wanted to figure it out.

I think someone (@fquinto) made something like what i want but he search on a Group names I want in Group messages.

[How to search for groups and channel in telegram using telethon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62016386/how-to-search-for-groups-and-channel-in-telegram-using-telethon)

@fquinto
https://stackoverflow.com/users/5824889/fquinto

Answer (score 2):

You can perform what's known as a "global" search with [`client`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.iter_messages) and searching in "no" chat (meaning, no particular chat, so globally). This will search in all of your dialogs:

```py
async for message in client.iter_messages(None, search='search'):
    ...
```

The search works in the same way as it does in official applications, so somewhat fuzzy search of a text, not "this word or this other word" (you can perform multiple searches for that).